# Dealing with time format greater than 24 hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, timedelta

I have data of experiments with time greater than 24 hours. For ex. `[23:24:44, 25:10:44]`. To operate duration of tests, I like to use Python, however I have a value error when I create datetime.time() with hours more than 23:59:.

Comment: What exact error? What code triggers it? Please show a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split your time by the colons in order to get a list of the component parts, which you could then use to initialise your timedelta:

```py
from datetime import timedelta

myDuration = "25:43:12"
mD = [int(x) for x in myDuration.split(":")]

delta = timedelta(hours=mD[0], minutes=mD[1], seconds=mD[2])
print(delta)
# 1 day, 1:43:12
```

Comment: To clarify for other readers. My goal is to compute time duration. I was confused and used datetime.time(hour=25, minute=43, second=12) which gives ValueError: hour must be in 0..23. However, datetime.time() is not a duration, datetime.timedelta() is the correct function for this case.